# Error when creating stored procedure SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am getting an error

> SQL Error (102): Incorrect syntax near ')'

when attempting to save the below query as a stored procedure.

The query itself (removing the "Create Procedure" and Begin/End works fine) and gives no syntax errors, and I have searched all over, however I am a bit stuck, and it is driving me insane.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE "downdaly_file_info"()
    LANGUAGE SQL
    NOT DETERMINISTIC
    CONTAINS SQL
    SQL SECURITY DEFINER
    COMMENT ''
begin
declare @file_name varchar(75)
declare @agent_number varchar(15)
declare @aid_batch varchar(15)
declare @aid_agent varchar(15)
declare @Policy_Company varchar(2)
declare @Policy_Province2 varchar(2)
declare @akey varchar(30)

select @aid_batch=aid from audit with(nolock) where atype='OUT-BATCH' and akey like '%'+@file_name+'%'
print @aid_batch
select @aid_agent=aid from audit with(nolock) where atype='OUT-AGENT' and aid like @aid_batch+'-%' and akey=@agent_number
print @aid_agent

select @akey=akey from audit with (nolock) where aid like @aid_agent+'-%' and atype='OUT-POLICY'

SET @Policy_Company=substring(@akey,15,2)
print @Policy_Company

SET @Policy_Province2 =
CASE
WHEN @Policy_Company = 'CG' THEN substring(@akey,19,2)
WHEN @Policy_Company = 'TR' THEN substring(@akey,20,2)
WHEN @Policy_Company = 'EL' THEN substring(@akey,20,2)
WHEN @Policy_Company = 'IC' THEN substring(@akey,22,2)
WHEN @Policy_Company = 'PI' THEN substring(@akey,20,2)
WHEN @Policy_Company = 'S&' THEN substring(@akey,20,2)
END
print @Policy_Province2

insert into #downdaly_file_data (Name_Of_File,
Agent_Number,
Policy_Number,
Transaction_Number,
Policy_Province,
Trans_Code,
Policy_Company,
Policy_Province2,
Eff_Date_Real
)
select @file_name,
@agent_number,
substring(akey,1,12),
SUBSTRING(adata,20,3),
substring(adata,171,2),
substring(adata,32,3),
@Policy_Company,
@Policy_Province2,
substring(adata,139,6)

from audit with (nolock)
where aid like @aid_batch+'%' and atype='OUT-POLICY'
end
```

Comment: Edit the question and add the exact error message.

Comment: You are using MySQL syntax...at least between your `CREATE` and your `BEGIN`...

Comment: [Bad habits : Putting NOLOCK everywhere](https://blogs.sentryone.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot add these information in procedure

```
LANGUAGE SQL
NOT DETERMINISTIC
CONTAINS SQL
SQL SECURITY DEFINER
COMMENT ''
```

Here is the possible options

```
CREATE { PROC | PROCEDURE } [schema_name.] procedure_name [ ; number ]   
    [ { @parameter [ type_schema_name. ] data_type }  
        [ VARYING ] [ = default ] [ OUT | OUTPUT | [READONLY]  
    ] [ ,...n ]   
[ WITH <procedure_option> [ ,...n ] ]  
[ FOR REPLICATION ]   
AS { [ BEGIN ]
```

Also when you don't have `parameters` don't add *parenthesis*. Here is the correct way

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Downdaly_file_info
AS
  BEGIN
  ---SQL statment
  END
```

Comment: Yup, I'm completely new at this, but the "Correct way" you mentioned worked perfect. Thank you!